# connexion with Oracle Visual Studio Community 2015 windowsForms

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms

I compiled my application as x64 bit and tried to run it on x64 , when, I add a new connexion Oracle , there was an Error :

**Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.**

I have searched to solve this issue  [here](http://nerictech.blogspot.com/2010/01/exception-oracle-64-bits-32-bits.html) , I does this change but, The issue persist again.

Can somebody have an idea ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the architecture to x86 as you gave the 32 bit drivers installed and 32 bit also will work on the 64bit architecture.  The other option is to find the 64 bit drivers amd then change the reference ot Oracle in the application to the 64 bit version